# How to update or insert millions of rows via node oracle-db?

Tags: node.js, oracle, sql-optimization, node-oracledb

I'm struggling with a question - how can I insert or update a lot of data (thousands or millions of rows) using node oracle-db driver?

The point is that I can select a lot of data with the help of resultSet ([handling result set](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#resultsethandling))... but then I have to make some actions with a row and later update or insert a new row. And here is the problem - I don't know how to do it as fast as possible.

Can anybody help me with a piece of advice? Thanks.

Comment: What are the "actions with a row" that need to be performed? In general, if you can do that in the database, rather than retrieving millions of rows back to a client or app server, you will be much better off...

Comment: I can assure you that these actions can't be done in db. For example, there is some kind of logic that takes a row from db, makes some calculations and then gives me a number. And this number I would like to insert (or update) into another table.

Comment: Taking a row, doing some calculations and getting a number sounds exactly the sort of thing a database is very good at!

Comment: OK, maybe it was not a good example... What about getting data from a row, parsing it with the help of a custom converter and getting an xml file as a result? I'm not an expert in db and sql stuff actually...

Comment: You can do a lot with PL/SQL. And if that is not good enough, you have Java running in the database. It will be faster whether by a factor 10, 100 or 1000 or more depends on the processing involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can assure you that these actions can't be done in db.

Actually, there are lots of different ways this can be done in the DB via SQL and PL/SQL when needed. Folks often want to use the language they are comfortable with, maybe JavaScript in this case, but performance will be much better if the data doesn't have to fly around between tiers.

Here's an example in just SQL alone... Granted, this could have been done via virtual columns, but it should illustrate the point.

Imagine we have the following tables:

```sql
create table things (
  id   number not null, 
  val1 number not null, 
  val2 number not null, 
  constraint things_pk primary key (id)
);

insert into things (id, val1, val2) values (1, 1, 2);
insert into things (id, val1, val2) values (2, 2, 2);
insert into things (id, val1, val2) values (3, 5, 5);

-- Will hold the sum of things val1 and val2
create table thing_sums (
  thing_id number,
  sum      number
);

alter table thing_sums
add constraint thing_sums_fk1 
foreign key (thing_id)
references things (id);
```

Now, the easiest and most performant way to do this would be via SQL:

```sql
insert into thing_sums (
  thing_id,
  sum
)
select id, 
  val1 + val2
from things
where id not in (
  select thing_id
  from thing_sums
);
```

Here's another example that does the same thing only via PL/SQL which can provide more control.

```sql
begin

  -- This cursor for loop will bulk collect (reduces context switching between 
  -- SQL and PL/SQL engines) implictly. 
  for thing_rec in (
    select *
    from things
    where id not in(
      select thing_id
      from thing_sums
    )
  )
  loop
    -- Logic in this loop could be endlessly complex. I'm inserting the values
    -- within the loop but this logic could be modified to store data in arrays
    -- and then insert with forall (another bulk operation) after the loop.
    insert into thing_sums(
      thing_id,
      sum
    ) values (
      thing_rec.id,
      thing_rec.val1 + thing_rec.val2
    );
  end loop;

end;
```

Either of those could be called from the Node.js driver. However, let's say you need to do this from the driver (maybe you're ingesting data that's not already in the database). Here's an example the demonstrates calling PL/SQL from the driver that uses bulk processing rather than row by row operations. This is much faster due to reduced round trips.

I pulled this from a blog post I'm working on so the table definition is a little different:

```sql
create table things (
  id   number not null,
  name varchar2(50),
  constraint things_pk primary key (id)
);
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var async = require('async');
var config = require('./dbconfig');
var things = [];
var idx;

function getThings(count) {
  var things = [];

  for (idx = 0; idx < count; idx += 1) {
    things[idx] = {
      id: idx,
      name: "Thing number " + idx
    };
  }

  return things;
}

things = getThings(500);

oracledb.getConnection(config, function(err, conn) {
  var ids = [];
  var names = [];
  var start = Date.now();

  if (err) {throw err;}

  // We need to break up the array of JavaScript objects into arrays that
  // work with node-oracledb bindings.
  for (idx = 0; idx < things.length; idx += 1) {
    ids.push(things[idx].id);
    names.push(things[idx].name);
  }

  conn.execute(
    ` declare
        type number_aat is table of number
          index by pls_integer;
        type varchar2_aat is table of varchar2(50)
          index by pls_integer;

        l_ids   number_aat := :ids;
        l_names varchar2_aat := :names;
      begin
        forall x in l_ids.first .. l_ids.last
          insert into things (id, name) values (l_ids(x), l_names(x));
      end;`,
    {
      ids: {
        type: oracledb.NUMBER,
        dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
        val: ids
      }, 
      names: {
        type: oracledb.STRING,
        dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
        val: names
      }
    },
    {
      autoCommit: true
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err) {console.log(err); return;}

      console.log('Success. Inserted ' + things.length + ' rows in ' + (Date.now() - start) + ' ms.');
    }
  );
});
```

I hope that helps! :)

Comment: That is great! I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!!! Btw, is your blog post in progress or I can find it on the internet?

Comment: That particular post isn't out yet, but you can visit the blog here: https://jsao.io/

Comment: @DanMcGhan's post is at https://jsao.io/2017/01/plsql-record-types-and-the-node-js-driver/